# Slicing a Pandas dataframe non-monotonic index

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, slice

I am trying to slice a DataFrame to return a specific portion of the time series. However, the time is stamped by week which has given me trouble.

```
df
       Week  one  two
0   12/3/2017    0    7
1   12/3/2017    6    1
2  12/10/2017    5    8
3  12/10/2017    2    4
4  12/17/2017    3    7
5  12/17/2017    2    0
6  12/24/2017    8    9
```

I have been trying to slice by setting the 'Week' column as the index and then using partial string indexing but I keep getting a Key Error saying "Cannot get left slice bound for non-unique label: '12/3/2017'"

```
df = df.set_index('Week')
df = df['12/3/2017':'12/17/2017']

KeyError: "Cannot get left slice bound for non-unique label: '12/3/2017'"
```

Any suggestions on how I can make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use `loc`.

```
df.loc['12/3/2017':'12/17/2017']

            one  two
Week                
12/3/2017     0    7
12/3/2017     6    1
12/10/2017    5    8
12/10/2017    2    4
12/17/2017    3    7
12/17/2017    2    0
```

This works with `v0.21`.

Comment: Thank you for helping! I tried using `loc` but I'm still getting the same Key Error unfortunately

Comment: @DH_III Try updating to `0.21` (I put the version at the bottom for that purpose).